# How to assign an unspecified class into an unspecified interface dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, unit-of-work

I want to assign a class to its interface. I am using a unit of work pattern.

We assume that we have multiple tables in our database and that we specify these tables with classes. I mentioned two of them. I want to access multiple tables on any controller, but I do not know how to integrate these tables(classes) into the interfaces.

How to assign `FirmApiProcessor`, `CompanyApiProcessor` to their interfaces dynamically in controller? I want to assign them like this:

```
ICompanyApi _companyApi = CreateProcessor(param);
```

like this :

```
ICompanyApi _companyApi = CreateProcessor(ICompanyApi);

IFirmApi _firmApi = CreateProcessor(IFirmApi);
```

instead of :

```
ICompanyApi _companyApi = new CompanyApiProcessor(uow);

IFirmApi _firmApi = new FirmApiProcessor(uow);
```

My interfaces:

```
public interface <Api<T> where T : BaseDto

public interface IParameterApi : IApi<ParameterDto>

public interface IFirmApi : IApi<FirmDto>
```

My classes:

```
public class BaseApiProcesssor<TDto, TEntity> : IApi<TDto> where TDto : BaseDto where TEntity : BaseEntity

public class CompanyApiProcessor : BaseApiProcesssor<CompanyDto, Company>, IParameterApi

public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    ICompanyApi _companyApi;
    IFirmApi _firmApi;

    public CompanyController(IUnitOfWork uow) // uow is created by dependency injection
    {
        // How to assign ??
        //
        //I can assign them like this. But this is not dynamic and not logical to use like this.

        // _companyApi = new CompanyApiProcessor(uow);
        // _firmApi = new FirmApiProcessor(uow);

        _companyApi = ???????
        _firmApi = ????????
    }
}

public class FirmApiProcessor : FirmApiProcesssor<FirmDto, Firm>, IFirmApi

public class FirmController : Controller
{
    IFirmApi _firmApi;

    public FirmController(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        // How to assign ??
        //
        //I can assign it like this. But this is not dynamic and not logical to use like this.

        // _firmApi = new FirmApiProcessor(uow);

        _firmApi = ????????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need a Dependency Injection Container, but you may keep it simple and follow this example:

```
ICompanyApi _companyApi = CreateProcessor<ICompanyApi>();
IFirmApi _firmApi = CreateProcessor<IFirmApi>();

public static T CreateProcessor<T>()
{
    if (T is ICompanyApi)
    {
        return new CompanyApiProcessor() as T;
    }
    else if (T is IFirmApi)
    {
        return new FirmApiProcessor() as T;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Unsupported type");
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you don't want to define mappings, you may try to find interface implementors using reflection:

```
public static T CreateProcessor<T>()
{
    var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(r => r.GetTypes())
        .Where(r => type.IsAssignableFrom(T));

    var type = types.FirstOrDefault(); // Selecting first found implementor
    if (type == null)
        throw new ApplicationException("Unsupported type");

    return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as T;
}
```

To avoid scanning your assemblies every time, you may add a dictionary and remember mappings.

Comment: But assume that i have 100 class. Company and Firm are 2 classes of them. I need to assign it dynamicly.

Comment: @ŞerefCanMuştu you may use `Reflection` to scan your assemblies for interface implementors, but this may work slowly.

Comment: I'll try that reflection method. Thanks

Comment: ups, i tried it now and i have a small problem. i use .NET CORE MVC. there is no appdomain in it. i'll research it tomorrow but if you know that in .net core, pls help. thanks